# NodeJS and ExpressJS parallel processing of rest request

Tags: node.js, express

I am newbie with JavaScript, NodeJS and Express. I writing simple application which does the following

1. User makes a request.
2. Server makes mulitple rest calls and renders the response.

How can I make sure that all the calls are complete and I create an object that I can send to the user? I saw people said something about async.parallel. Is that the only way to go? Any examples would help.

Comment: I use promises whenever I do that. Just google for examples, try some and then come back if you have a specific problem

Comment: To expand on Aidin, search Promise.all

Answer (score 1):

You can use promises to run code in sequence. 
Here is an example (a little scaled down) of a login functionality I made using promises.

In a module named `LoginController` I have placed this piece of code.

```
this.attemptLogin = function(body, res) {
    var reason = "";
    var user = null;

    loginM.findUser(body.username)
        .then(function(result) {
            if (result.status) {
                user = result.result[0];
                return this.verifyPassword(body.password, result.result[0].Password);
            } else {
                reason = {status: false, message: "Incorrect username", result: null};
                throw(reason);
            }
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            if (result.message) {
                res.send({status: true, message: "Successfully logged in", result: user});
                return;
            } else {
                reason = {status: false, message: "Incorrect password", result: null};
                throw(reason);
            }
        }).catch(function(err) {
            res.send(err);
        });
}
```

And in another module named `LoginModel` (`LoginM`) I have placed this code

```
this.findUser = function(username, email) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                reject({status: false, message: err});
            } else {
                connection.query('select Id, Name, Email, Password from Users ' +
                'where (Users.Name = ? OR Users.Email = ?) AND Removed = 0 LIMIT 1', [username, email], function (err, rows) {
                    connection.release();
                    if (!err) {
                        if(rows.length > 0) {
                            resolve({status: true, message: "Found user", result: rows});
                        }
                        else 
                            resolve({status: false, message: null})
                    } else {
                        reject({status: false, message: err});
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And a similar method for `verifyPassword` which also returns a promise.

Now, the things to note are that:

- the code inside every `then` is run asynchronously
- the `then` parts are executed in order, i.e, you won´t enter the next `then` until you have returned something from the previous `then`
- whatever you `resolve` from the methods returning promises (`findUser` and `verifyPassword`) are passed as the variable named `result` in `.then(function(result)`

Comment: Awesome I will try this out!